# #Value Error in User Defined Function VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am writing a function to find the first row that has a different interior color (with Conditional Formatting) above the current active cell. The function works when I print it out with `debug.print` or `msgbox` but not when I call it directly in the worksheet. The first row is header and that's why I exclude the top row.

```
Public Function blockStart() As Long
    Dim currColor As Long
    currColor = activecell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex

    Dim currCol As String
    currCol = Number2Letter(activecell.Column)

    Dim startRow As Long
    startRow = activecell.Row

    'Find Ceiling
    Do While startRow >= 2
        If Range(currCol & startRow).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> currColor Then
            startRow = startRow + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        startRow = startRow - 1
    Loop

    If startRow = 1 Then startRow = 2   ' at the very top

    blockStart = startRow

End Function
```

When I call the function directly in the worksheet, `#value` is prompted. Please let me know what I am doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately `DisplayFormat` doesn't work with UDF's...

Comment: Really? I thought the not working part is actually to change something, but reading from it doesn't work as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but in any case, a UDF when called in a worksheet will not work with `DisplayFormat`.

Comment: Did some research and it actually turns out to be the case... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just so you're not left feeling like this is impossible, one possible approach to doing what you want to do is to take the entire body of your BlockStart function and put it in the Worksheet's SelectionChange event. Then, instead of the line that says `blockStart = startRow` you can assign the value to startRow to the cell where you are trying to use the BlockStart function.

If multiples cells use the BlockStart function, assign the value to an unused cell somewhere and have the other cells reference it.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! I am not sure if that is going to work for me though since I will include in more than 30,000 cells...